# How to user Firebase user UID as ID in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm new to Firebase and I don't understand how to save a user in a collection. So, I have the code below and I need to modify it to save a document in 'users' collection where document id is equal to UID of the user. Firebase generete an ID for every new docuement I add, but I want to set this generated ID to be the UID of the user. I'm using Angular 10 and Firebase to do that. Can you help me achive that please?

```
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

createUser(email: string, password: string, userData: RegisterDataModel) {
    return defer(async () => {
      const cred = await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );
      return cred.user;
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        console.log({ ...userData, userId: user?.uid });
        return this.addUserDb({ ...userData, userId: user?.uid });
      })
    );
  }

  private addUserDb(user: RegisterDataModel) {
    const url = `some random API`;
    return this.httpClient.post(url, user);
  }
```

Comment: I cannot see any code related with Firestore. Where is the `addUserDb` function trying to add the data?

Comment: I add the user calling the API provided by firebase using post. Every collection offers you a way to get all the data, to insert data in that collection, to delete data, etc